# Simplify a summation to the harmonic series

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

I've been given the following as a solution to a problem I'm working on, but I do not understand how to jump from step 1 to step 2. Kindly help me formulate an intermediate step between (1) and (2) to help me understand the solution.

[image]

Comment: Call $i-j+1$ as $k$. Then as $j$ runs between $1$ and $i-1$, $k$ runs between $2$ and $i$ (backwards but summation is commutative). Similarly for the other sum.

Comment: I don't quite see this yet.

Comment: How about this? $$
\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{i - 1} {\frac{1}{{i - j + 1}}}  = \frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{{i - 1}} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{i - 1}} + \frac{1}{i} = \sum\limits_{k = 2}^i {\frac{1}{k}} .
$$

Comment: I misread your previous comment. Yes. This makes sense. Thank you.